# Git2-rs status of files in commit log

Tags: git, rust, libgit2

Can I find out in Git2-rs / libgit2 about the status of a file like added/removed/modified from the commit log? I've looked at the documentation but only find Diff Trees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, there's no direct access to the status of a specific path but you can use the [`statuses`](https://docs.rs/git2/0.13.20/git2/struct.Repository.html#method.statuses) function of a repository to iterate over all the statuses it knows and look at the path of each [`StatusEntry`](https://docs.rs/git2/0.13.20/git2/struct.StatusEntry.html).

To make it more efficient if you have several paths for which you'd like to know the status, you can do the iteration, build a map from paths to statuses, then query this map for every path you're interested in.

Comment: Here's an example of such computation in broot: https://github.com/Canop/broot/blob/master/src/git/status.rs#L31

Comment: I had a similar problem and got some inspiration from these [samples](https://github.com/rust-lang/git2-rs/issues/588).
Hope, you'll find them useful.